# Logic problem (using last row value) with Kelly criterion application - python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a logic issue when trying to build a model with kelly criterion using python. I need a value to be used from the previous row(cell) for the function, however, the previous row(cell) is the index row when i tried to apply the function for the entire df.

Below is the the code and output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Probability':[0.3,0.4,0.5],
'Odds':[5,1,4]
,'Cap':[1000,'','']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

P = df.Probability / 1
B = df.Odds
Q = 1 - P
df['Kelly'] = ((B * P - Q)/B)

df['Invest'] = df.Kelly * df.Cap

df.loc[df['Invest'] < 0, 'Invest'] = 0

df['Net'] = df.Odds * df.Invest

df['Total'] = df.Cap  + df.Net
```

Original DF

```
+---+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   | Probability | Odds | Cap  | Kelly  | Invest |  Net   | Total  |
+---+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 0 | 0.3         |    5 | 1000 | 0.160  | 160.0  | 800.0  | 1800.0 |
| 1 | 0.4         |    1 |      | -0.200 | 0.0    | 0.0    | 0.0    |
| 2 | 0.5         |    4 |      | 0.375  | 0.0    | 0.0    | 0.0    |
+---+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

DF of result im trying to achieve:
Where Cap(capital) is updated with Total from the previous row:

```
+---+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   | Probability | Odds | Cap  | Kelly  | Invest |  Net   | Total  |
+---+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 0 | 0.3         |    5 | 1000 | 0.160  | 160.0  | 800.0  | 1800.0 |
| 1 | 0.4         |    1 | 1800 | -0.200 | 0.0    | 0.0    | 1800.0 |
| 2 | 0.5         |    4 | 1800 | 0.375  | 675.0  | 2700.0 | 4500.0 |
+---+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

In summary, the Cap of 1000 from the first row is the initial capital and Total is the sum of Net + Cap. Therefore, after the first iteration, the following Cap will be the Total from the previous row.

I've tried using shift(-1), however, the first row won't be able to find Total from the last row since the last row is the index row.

Many thanks Regards

I've tried adding shift as recommended by @Daniel Geffen, however, i'm unable to solve the problem. am i placing the code in the wrong order or am i missing something?
This is the altered code:

```
P = df.Probability / 1
B = df.Odds
Q = 1 - P

df['Kelly'] = ((B * P - Q)/B)

df["Total"] = np.nan

df['Cap'] = df.Total.shift(1, fill_value=1000)

df['Invest'] = df.Kelly * df.Cap

df.loc[df['Invest'] < 0, 'Net'] = 0

df['Net'] = df.Odds * df.Invest

df['Total'] = df.Cap  + df.Net

df = df[['Probability', 'Odds','Cap','Kelly','Invest', 'Net', 'Total']]
```

This is the result with the altered code:

```
╔═══╦═════════════╦══════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║   ║ Probability ║ Odds ║  Cap   ║ Kelly  ║ Invest ║  Net  ║ Total  ║
╠═══╬═════════════╬══════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ 0 ║ 0.3         ║    5 ║ 1000.0 ║ 0.160  ║ 160.0  ║ 800.0 ║ 1800.0 ║
║ 1 ║ 0.4         ║    1 ║ NaN    ║ -0.200 ║ NaN    ║ NaN   ║ NaN    ║
║ 2 ║ 0.5         ║    4 ║ NaN    ║ 0.375  ║ NaN    ║ NaN   ║ NaN    ║
╚═══╩═════════════╩══════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

Comment: You probably need to explain more about you problem statement.

Comment: Thanks @Shakeel, i should have added more information at the beginning of my question instead of the bottom. I've added the necessary. Do let me know if more information is required. Cheers –

Comment: "Cap(capital) should be updated with Total from the last row." - It's unclear what that means. Do you mean the previous row? Why does `Total` change too, between the two dataframes you show?

Comment: Sorry @Arne, i've not being using OS for a while and i have problem with inputting tables and separating them according, therefore, some confusion on my question. I've added more info and separate the table accordingly. Hope this clears up the questions.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon How's your `Net` column calculated, it seems mismatched in the data you provided.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSharma, Net = Invest * Odds. In the first row Odds is 5 and invest is 160. Which gives the Net of 800.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon What about `2700`?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma,  Third row: Odds is 4 and Invest is 675; which is 4 * 675 = 2700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have various variables that need to be updated sequentially, because every value depends on the previous one. In that case, I don't see a better way than to do it row by row:

```py
# starting with your original df, not repeated here

for row in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[row, 'Cap'] = df.Total[row - 1]
    df.loc[row, 'Invest'] = df.Kelly[row] * df.Cap[row]
    df.loc[row, 'Net'] = df.Odds[row] * df.Invest[row]
    df.loc[row, 'Total'] = df.Cap[row] + df.Net[row]

df
```

```py
    Probability     Odds    Cap     Kelly   Invest  Net     Total
0   0.3             5       1000.0  0.160   160.0   800.0   1800.0
1   0.4             1       1800.0  -0.200  -360.0  -360.0  1440.0
2   0.5             4       1440.0  0.375   540.0   2160.0  3600.0
```

However, note that this does not quite produce the same dataframe as the one you desired, so maybe I'm still misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes, you are right. the variables needed to be updated sequentially because the values are correlated to the previous one. Hence, i'm having problems finding a solution to code them in a logical way.. Your solution solved a big part of the issue, however, i need sometime to digest how the "row by row" method you mentioned. Get back to you soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should be using `shift(1)` in order to get the values from the previous row. Using the `fill_value` parameter can fill the first row with your initial value:

```
df['Cap'] = df.Total.shift(1, fill_value=1000)
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, however, as Cap is part of the function. When i tried your solution, it didn't update the entire function.